# Slider on Money value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider, datatables

Has anyone successfully used the Jquery Slider with the DataTables plugin?

I need to provide a slider for a money range. the table is built using server side processing Ajax call on a C# app.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

so with the above example the values are hard coded, i need a way of getting the max / min from the amount column in the dataTable

Comment: no one done this then :-)

Comment: Anyone? Surely someone must be out there